# CSS vertical alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my `<div>` and my `<button>` to occupy the same space vertically. They each have a `height:20px` style but as you can see there is space below my `<div>` tag and space above my `<button>` tag. 
What should I do so that both my `<div>` and `<button>` tag take up the SAME 20px?

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
div,
p,
button {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.boxes {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

#next {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box0">
  <p class="boxes" id="boxes0">

  </p>
  <button id="next" onclick="switcher()">Guess</button>
</div>
```

My jsfiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/pb4759jh68/37bfhxdr/4/

Comment: `vertical-align` is your friend with `inline-block` elements... (also, `0px` is redundant - `0` is unitless, so just write `padding: 0;`)

Comment: Try flexbox you'll love it

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with inline-block elements you set the vertical-align property to middle on both of your .boxes and .next classes

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
div,
p,
button {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.boxes {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#next {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="box0">
  <p class="boxes" id="boxes0">

  </p>
  <button id="next" onclick="switcher()">Guess</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Deleting my answer, this one has an explanation. Though not that you can also vertically align to the bottom and this will still work.